# blocking an input box with respect to dropdownlist value

Tags: jsp

I have tow drop down list, ids are cType and cId. Another input box named newName.
Now I want to make my input box enable when I select EXTERNAL in cType or others in cId.
I made this thing . But not working.

```
function blockName(){
var dis1 = document.getElementsByname('cType').value;
var dis2 = document.getElementById('cId').value;
if (dis1 == 'EXTERNAL'|| dis2== '3')
    newName.disabled = false;

else
    newName.disabled = true;

}
```

the drop down lists are-

```
<tr>
<th colspan="1" align="right" > Type : </th>
<th colspan="1" align="left" style="width: 50px" >
<form:select path="" id="cType" onkeypress="blockName()">
<form:option value="X" label=" Select "/>
<form:option value="INTERNAL" label="student"/>
<form:option value="EXTERNAL" label="outsider"/>
</form:select>
</th>

<th align="left" >
<form:select name="cId" path="cId" id="cId" onkeypress="blockName()">
<form:option value="0" label="Select"/>
<form:option value="1" label="a"/>
<form:option value="2" label="b"/>
<form:option value="3" label="other"/>
</form:select>
</th>
```

and the input box is

```
<th colspan="1" align="left">                       
<form:input class="iptext" id="newName" path="" name="newName" value="" placeholder="Name" disabled="true"></form:input>
</th>
```

Comment: You need to give onchange() in select tag , newName is defined rght?

Comment: I have placed onchange(), but not working. Sorry, I do not understand where to define newName? @BharathRallapalli

Comment: you need to disable it using document.getElementById("newName").disabled=true;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make changes as following:
In javascript, you need to call getElementById and not getElementsByName. Also newName can be disabled/enabled by getElementById:

```
    function blockName(){
        var dis1 = document.getElementById('cType').value;
        var dis2 = document.getElementById('cId').value;
        if (dis1 == 'EXTERNAL'|| dis2== '3'){
            document.getElementById('newName').disabled = false;
        }else{
            document.getElementById('newName').disabled = true;
        }
    }
```

When you are using spring form tag, you don't have to use name attribute as path attribute will take care of it. For this enable disbale javascript function to be invokde on drop down change, you need to call onchange and not onkeypress function as:

```
    <form:select path="cType" id="cType" onchange="blockName()">
    <form:option value="X" label=" Select "/>
    <form:option value="INTERNAL" label="student"/>
    <form:option value="EXTERNAL" label="outsider"/>
    </form:select>

    <form:select path="cId" id="cId" onchange="blockName()">
    <form:option value="0" label="Select"/>
    <form:option value="1" label="a"/>
    <form:option value="2" label="b"/>
    <form:option value="3" label="other"/>
    </form:select>

    <form:input class="iptext" id="newName" path="newName" placeholder="Name" disabled="true"></form:input>
```